# Hubspot API v3 upload bulk of contact

Tags: upload, contacts, batch-processing, hubspot

Can anyone help me or give an example of c# or curl of hubspot api v3 request that upload bulk of contacts as marketing contact, and the other as unmarketable contact. I tried to research and read the documentation of hubspot but it's hard for me to understand how to this. Thank you in advance.

I tried using the v1 of hubspot, it's working but it don't marked as marketing contact.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a [private app](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/private-apps) in HubSpot that can read/write contacts.

Once the above is done, you will need to create a script that will loop through a CSV file (or whichever file format your contacts are written in) and then push these contacts on by one to HubSpot using the [HubSpot contacts API](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/contacts). As far as I know, HubSpot API V3 doesn't have a feature for batch pushing contacts, so you will need to push these contacts one by one. HubSpot API V1 does have a feature for batch pushing contacts, see [here](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/batch_create_or_update).